# Flash AS3 - Trying to access public function from another class throws error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my Main.as:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {
           // Code here
        }

        public function myFunc() {
            trace('!!!!');
        }
    }
}
```

When I try accessing it from another class using the following code, Flash throws me Error #2136:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Main;

    public class MyClass extends MovieClip {
        public var m:Main;

        public function MyClass() {
            m = new Main();
            m.myFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: One more thing. The second class is attached to a MovieClip and exported on the first frame. I thought it made no difference, but someone in the comments have told me it does and apparently that's what's causing the error in the first place. In that case, how can I access the public function from a class attached to a MC?

Comment: The code that you have posted is OK. The error must be in other side. The `Error #2136` consists in invalid data in the `SWF`. Check if you do not have any `MovieClip`exported as runtime with one of those class names or check for other type of conflicts. But I repeat it again, the code that you have posted is OK.

Comment: Well, the class IS attached to a MovieClip. I'm sorry, I didn't know it made a difference.

Comment: In principle there is no difference. In principle if you have attached this class to a `MovieClip` there is no reason to appear that error. I only recommend you that check all the `Symbols` exported in the runtime, maybe you have this `Class` name in other parts. Your error is in other place not in the calling method part. The code that you posted is OK.

Comment: Well, the movieclip is placed directly on the stage through Flash rather than added through addChild. I've then tried to add it using addChild, but that generates yet another error (undefined method.) Are those movieclips with classes even meant to be in the stage in the first place?

Comment: Here you have an `FLA` with your code. There is not error at all.
Like I said in the before comments, the error is in other part of your code. The code that you posted is OK. [download FLA](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/ExampleClasses.zip)

Comment: I am developing using Flash CS3, this is made with ActionScript 3. Could this be the reason why?

Comment: I do not know why, it should not do it, if you are coding with `AS3` not matters the version of Flash that you have. My FLA throws an error to you?

Comment: I couldn't open with CS3, it says the file's invalid. I've tested the code with another function other than Main and it works. Maybe Flash CS3/Flash Player 9 has a problem with that. I might aswell just use another class entirely, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time post the error message itself, most of us do not have Flash errors memorized by id. ;)

From [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html):

> 2136  The SWF file %1 contains invalid data.

This rings a bell for me. Your `Main` class is probably your document class. The document class is a special class that **cannot be instantiated**.

---

To access properties and methods of the document class instance from other code, you simply need a reference to the document class instance.

There are many ways you could get a reference, as it is really just a code dependency design question. Two common, easy solutions are:

**1.** Use the [`root`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#root) property of any display object that is added as a child of the document class instance. Since the `root` property is typed to `DisplayObject` you need to cast to your document class to access its methods and property, for example: `Main(root).myFunc()`.

**2.** Use the singleton pattern and assign a static public reference to the document class instance:

```
public class Main {
    public static var main:Main;
    public function Main() {
        main = this;
    }
    public function myFunc():void { }
}

// usage:
Main.main.myFunc();
```

Comment: In this case, how can I call a variable/function from the document class?

Comment: You need access to the document class instance. There's many ways to get a reference, but usually the easiest is to use the [`root`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#root) property of any display object that has been added to the stage.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. My problem is solved :)